# How do I solve for x? Do I need the Lambert W function?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, problem-solving, lambert-w

I need to solve the next equation x:

$d-x+yln[\frac{d}{x}]=b$

y, d, b, and x are all real, positive numbers.

How do I solve for x? Do use the lambert W function and if so how is that done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=y t$ in order to get
$$ t - \log\frac{d}{t y} = \frac{d-b}{y} $$
that is equivalent to:
$$ t\cdot e^t = \frac{d}{y}\cdot e^{\frac{d-b}{y}} $$
so:

> $$ x = y\cdot W\left(\frac{d}{y}\cdot e^{\frac{d-b}{y}}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}d-x+y\ln\frac dx &= b\\
d +y\ln d-x-y\ln x &= b\\
d + y\ln \frac dy - \frac {yx}y - y\ln\frac xy &= b\\
d + y\ln \frac dy - b &= y\left(\frac xy + \ln\frac xy\right)\\
d + y\ln \frac dy - b &= y\ln\left(\frac xy\exp\frac xy\right)\\
\frac xy\exp\frac xy &= \exp\left(\frac{d - b}{y}+\ln\frac dy\right)\\
\frac xy\exp\frac xy &= \frac dy\exp\frac{d - b}{y}\\
\frac xy &= W\left(\frac dy\exp\frac{d - b}{y}\right)\\
x &= yW\left(\frac dy\exp\frac{d-b}y\right)\\
\end{align*}$$